# How to run powershell job in parallel on AzureDevops Hosted pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**-EDIT 03-**

I am editing my question because comments are too small.

I finally got my task to run. I had to edit the `Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication` to accept a "compareApplicationName" and a "compareMode". It would then use those to determine a list of services that would get upgraded. I had to be careful not to unRegister the ApplicationType until I was done upgrading all the applications.

I'm sorry but my legal department will not allow me to post any actual code, claiming it as IP for the company.

**-EDIT 02-**

User Error
It turns out `Get-VstsInput` does not return any value when called from a thread. So any and all evaluations were wrong and the error was getting swallowed by the thread.
I'm rewriting to just thread the call to `Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication`.

**-Original message-**

I have a service fabric cluster with several services running. Some of these are dynamically created services so they are not referenced in the ServiceManifest.xml

I have a custom task that updates the dynamically created services in series but this takes hours. I am trying to run `Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication` in parallel so I can run all the upgrade jobs at once. The jobs start (I think) but the task never waits for them to finish before ending (and, thus, ending the PS jobs).

I've tried adding a `Do...While` loop on the job state but it still ends the task prematurely.

How do I keep the task alive while the upgrade is running?

**-EDIT-**

I feel I need to provide a sample because my code is not working the way it's supposed to. Given this code in the task:

```
    foreach($serviceapp in $servicefabricapp){
        if(-not ($serviceapp.ApplicationName.OriginalString.StartsWith("fabric:/DynamicService"))) {
            Write-Host "Application '$($serviceapp.ApplicationName.OriginalString)' does not start with 'fabric:/DynamicService' -SKIPPING"
            continue 
        }

        $foundTaxReturnApp = $true
        Write-Host "Starting upgrade for $($serviceapp.ApplicationName.OriginalString)"
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $upgradeScriptBlock -ArgumentList $serviceapp.ApplicationName, $applicationPackagePath, $applicationParameterFile, $publishProfile, $isUpgrade, $upgradeParameters

        Start-Sleep 5
    }

    $jobCount = (Get-Job | Where-Object{ $_.state -eq 'Running'}).Count

    Do {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        Write-Host "Waiting for $jobCount jobs to finish..."
        $jobCount = (Get-Job | Where-Object{ $_.state -eq 'Running'}).Count
    } while ($jobCount -gt 0)

    Get-Job

    $jobCount = (Get-Job | Where-Object{ $_.state -eq 'Running'}).Count

    Write-Host "Finished waiting, $jobCount jobs running."
```

This is the output to the pipeline. There is no time elapsed between "upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2019OA20200131__16_21_39" and "Waiting for 0 jobs to finish...". And none of the DynamicServices get upgraded.

```
Application 'fabric:/MyFabricSystem' does not start with 'fabric:/DynamicService' -SKIPPING
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-PSWorkflowSession'.
VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'nwsn'.

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018CA20200128__13_35_06
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018FA20200130__16_12_16
5      Job5            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018GA20200130__16_12_16
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018IA20200131__16_21_39
9      Job9            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018IB20200131__16_21_39
11     Job11           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018KA20200121__15_08_01
13     Job13           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018OA20200131__16_21_39
15     Job15           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018PA20200131__16_21_39
17     Job17           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018SA20200130__16_12_16
19     Job19           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018XA20200127__16_43_45
21     Job21           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2018YA20200124__15_17_35
23     Job23           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2019GA20200130__16_12_16
25     Job25           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Starting upgrade for fabric:/DynamicService-2019OA20200131__16_21_39
27     Job27           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
Waiting for 0 jobs to finish...
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
3      Job3            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
5      Job5            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
7      Job7            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
9      Job9            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
11     Job11           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
13     Job13           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
15     Job15           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
17     Job17           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
19     Job19           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
21     Job21           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
23     Job23           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
25     Job25           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
27     Job27           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
Finished waiting, 0 jobs running.
##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\DynamicServiceUpgrade_4ec0e9dc-0f0a-47ff-86e3-ca0ae22d21d9\0.0.31\taskmain.ps1.
```

Comment: How's the issue going after you rewriting to just thread the call to `Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication`?

Comment: Current status: unwinding the mess I made took longer than I wanted so I am starting over with a copy of ServiceFabricDeploy@1 and looping for the dynamic applications.

Comment: This looks like it's going to be a significant rewrite of ```Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication```. The main issue being PS Jobs are run outside the current context. So any calls to the ServiceFabricSDK are going to fail (i.e. the ```ValidateScript``` on ```Invoke-ActionWithRetries``` failes because it can't convert System.Fabric.FabricTransientException correctly.)
My next stop is to move the Start-Job inside to the ```Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgradeAction``` and, if that doesn't work, to the ``` Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade``` at the bottom.
I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance the script is executing properly. The concept of the Job is to execute and move on. If you would like to wait for the jobs to finish simply `Get-Job | Wait-Job` after your all of Jobs have executed.

If you want to do something a little more advanced/smart you can put it in your do-while loop

```
Do {
 $Job = Get-Job
 if ($Job.Status -eq "Failed") {
  "Fail"
  Exit 1
 }
Sleep 10
} Until ($Job.Status -eq "Success")
```

Comment: I added example code to illustrate my problem more clearly.

Comment: Is it OK without the Get-VSTSInput?

If not, given all the extra details in your post, it's more likely that the issue is in your `Start-Job` statement. The syntax looks OK so the command is valid, but the correct arguments or script block might not be passed through. Have you tested `Start-Job` with the relevant static values locally?

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it does, in fact, answer my original question (as opposed to what my question turned into).